# Joining two dataframes on subvalue of the key column

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, substring

I am currently trying to join / merge two df on the column Key, where in df1 the key is a standalone value such as 5, but in df2, the key can consist of multiple values such as [5,6,13].
For example like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': [["5","6","13"],["10","7"],["6","8"]]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'sub_key': ["5","10","6"]})
```

However, my df are a lot bigger and consist of many columns, so an efficient solution would be great.

As a result I would like to have a table like this:

| Key1 | Key2 |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 5,6,13 |
| 10 | 10,7 |

and so on ....

I already tried to apply this approach to my code, but it didn't work:

```
df1['join'] = 1
df2['join'] = 1
merged= df1.merge(df2, on='join').drop('join', axis=1)
df2.drop('join', axis=1, inplace=True)
merged['match'] = merged.apply(lambda x: x.key(x.sub_key), axis=1).ge(0)
```

I also tried to split and explode the column and to join on single values, however there the problem was, that not all column values were split correctly and I would need to combine everything back into one cell once joined.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to match the first key:

```
df1['sub_key'] = df1.key.str[0]
df1.merge(df2)
```

If you want to match ANY key:

```
df3 = df1.explode('key').rename(columns={'key':'sub_key'})
df3 = df3.join(df1)
df3.merge(df2)
```

Edit: First version had a small bug, fixed it.

Comment: Hey @hirolau, 
thank you for your solution, but I am facing an issue with this. 
If I have key and sub_key in df3, they are no longer matching. For example in key I have a 13 and in sub_key a 6.

Comment: I think you will need to elaborate on how you want to join the two frames. What logic should be used to consider the key matching with the sub_key.